# cannot insert list of maps to Apache Cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax

This is my schema

```
CREATE TABLE app_category_agg (
    category text,
    app_count int,
    sp_count int,
    subscriber_count int,
    window_revenue bigint,
    top_apps frozen <list<map<text,int>>>,
    PRIMARY KEY (category)
);
```

insert query generated by java is in this form

```
INSERT INTO analytics_info.app_category_agg (category,app_count,sp_count,subscriber_count, window_revenue,top_apps) VALUES ('Entertainment',3,2,65,1620,[{APP_992984515=30}, {APP_991415478=23}, {APP_999095235=12}]);
```

> issue is with '=' sign in the map objects in the list of maps. How can
> I insert it correctly? in java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

map value should be specified as `{key1:val1, key2:val2}` (see [docs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_using/useInsertMap.html)), in your case it should be a

```
[{'APP_992984515':30}, {'APP_991415478':23}, {'APP_999095235':12}]
```

but really, you shouldn't generate literal query yourself, as it could be a complex task - you need to handle quotes correctly, etc.

More appropriate will be to use [prepared statements, and bind values](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.8/manual/statements/prepared/) - in this case, all syntax will be handled by driver.

Another possibility is to use Object Mapper (doc for [driver 3.x](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.8/manual/object_mapper/), [driver 4.x](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.7/manual/mapper/)) - in this case, you may work with rows in the table using the Java objects, all conversion will be handled by driver as well.

Comment: thanks for the answer, How can I map this again to an object in java. i get this error         
 "   Codec not found for requested operation: [map<varchar, int> <-> java.util.Map]; "

Comment: can you show a piece of code that you use - it's for insert or for select?

Comment: I posted it as a question                   
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62694080/codec-not-found-for-requested-operation-mapvarchar-int-java-util-map